# Ionic Framework app works with "ionic serve" but not in Ionic View app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a very small Ionic app I've been working on (just a couple angular routes/views). When I run it using "ionic serve", the app loads in my browser as expected. However, when I upload it using "ionic upload" and view it in the Ionic View app, it appears as though none of my javascript works, or my routes are not working.

How can I debug this issue? Are there build tools to detect errors or anything along those lines?

Comment: I am unsure about Ionic View App, but I use Android SDK tools to compile and install my application. Then I use ADB to view the debug log using: `adb logcat CordovaLog:D *:S`. Alternatively, you can use Chrome's remote debugging `WebView` facility if you have a device having Anrdoid 4.4+(Kitkat or higher) - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Great, thank you! I will try that out to see if it shows me any errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Keval says if you're running Android you can debug on-the-fly using Chrome

1. enable Developer options on your device (Settings > About, then find Build number and keep tapping it...yes really!)
2. In Developer options, enable USB debugging checkbox
3. plug in with a USB cable
4. run your app on the device.
5. At some point your device will then show a popup requiring you to accept debug commands from the remote computer, click Accept. If it doesn't appear the first time, unplug and replug usually fixes it
6. head to chrome://inspect in desktop Chrome, and click inspect under your device
7. A new Chrome window will open with all the juicy abilities you need - inspect code, set breakpoints, look at network speeds, access the console and so on

You can also do this on iOS via Safari http://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-concise-guide-to-remote-debugging-on-ios-android-and-windows-phone/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. The problem was that I stored my Ionic views NOT in `/templates` folder.

Please, check, maybe my answer will be useful for you.

Comment: He not means html `views` , he means the ionic view app in google play, search `ionic view` in google play.